# VF outputtext with value if contains condition and currency format

Tags: visualforce, email, visualforce-template

I want to format my Amount with currency and at the same time use the condition `contains`, bur I'm not sure how to put it

Currency is working:

```
<apex:outputText  value="{0, number, currency}" rendered="{!relatedTo.Amount < 25000 }">
<apex:param value="{!ABS(relatedTo.Amount)}" />. 
</apex:outputText>
```

but I need to add another condition using `if contains`. Below is not working when using value with currency format and `if contains`

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, number, currency} {!if(CONTAINS(relatedTo.Product_Details_vfe__c,"Esri Inc") &&  relatedTo.Amount < 25000,
'<br>this ' + RelatedTo.Amount + '</br>
','')}" escape="false"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can decompose the problem into pieces

- The rendering condition (in a wrapper outputPanel)
- The markup including formatted currency

  ```
  <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!CONTAINS(relatedTo.Product_Details_vfe__c,'Esri Inc') &&
                            relatedTo.Amount < 25000}">
    ..somemarkup.. 
    <apex:outputText value="{0, number, currency}">
      <apex:param value="{!ABS(relatedTo.Amount)}" /> 
    </apex:outputText>
    ..more markup
  </apex:outputPanel>
  ```

Comment: This is VF email template, is apex:outputPanel will work on email template?

Comment: Yep, no problem

Comment: Hi Cropedy... tried you code by got this error "apex:outputPanel" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</apex:outputPanel>"


<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!CONTAINS(relatedTo.Product_Details_vfe__c,"Esri Inc") && relatedTo.Amount < 25000}">
       <apex:outputText value="{0, number, currency}">
        <apex:param value="{!ABS(relatedTo.Amount)}" />
    </apex:outputText>
</apex:outputPanel>

Comment: @Smurfet - fixed - had doublequotes around Esri ... when it should have been single quotes